# PrestaShop 1.7 override src file in own module

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I create own module and I want to override some file so in views folder I create folder PrestaShop and in it I add complete path to file like `Admin/Catalog/Product/List/somefile.php` and this override works, but when I want override file from `src` folder there is nothing happend. For example I want to override file `public_html/src/Adapter/Product/PriceCalculator.php` so in my module I have `public_html/modules/mycustommodule/views/PrestaShop/src/Adapter/Product/PriceCalculator.php` and this is not work. There is any possibility to override those files?

Comment: refer this link : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views/

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible to override this folder, you can't overrides of other things than classes/controllers/modules with /override/ directory is not available anymore.
You can reed informations about that in their post : [planned to ovverride](http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#is-there-any-change-planned-to-the-override-system)

Comment: prestashop says "There are limitations and risks of using overrides. Keep them for your own shop."

more https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/